# Newsletter and bulk email service

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a good service to send Email newsletters. I send a couple of product news letters a month to about 6,000 registered clients

Can you guys recommend a good service?

- It would be nice if it had feedback
- Some kind of statistic
- A simple way to upload my Emails
- A simple way to upload my news letter
- A test mode of some kind
- And of course as low cost as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following comparison table for [email marketing services](http://www.email-marketing-options.com/) may help you choose the one fitting you:

[image]

Direct links to the services in the table:

- [GetResponse](http://www.getresponse.com/)
- [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com)
- [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com)
- [Benchmark Email](http://www.benchmarkemail.com)
- [Vertical Response](http://www.verticalresponse.com)
- [Campaigner](http://www.campaigner.com)
- [iContact](http://www.icontact.com)

Answer (score 4):

[Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

or you could try verticalresponse.com no monthly fees just per email costs

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp is by far the easiest to use.

One thing to consider, though, is where you got your list you want to target. MailChimp is very, very selective (and they do question you) of how you put your list together.  Any bought lists is off limits.

If your list is a bought list - you may want to try Vertical Response or Constant Contact, they are great solutions too and are a little more relaxed on the uploads.

Answer (score 0):

[Banckle Campaign](http://banckle.com/apps/campaign/overview.html) application will suit your needs well.

An application, focused on small businesses, has an easy to use User Interface with good reporting, template preparation, campaign preview and contacts management features. From different available plans, Business plan will suffice your 6000 registered clients requirement.

A free plan is also on your discretion which gives 14000 emails p/m to 2500 subscribers. I am from the Banckle Evangelists Team, striving to help people to learn more about Banckle Apps for their business success.